# Countering Perspective Effect

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a trapeze effect on a div. I'm using perspective to give shape to the div. But what I can't work out is how to make the content inside normal. I can't get the settings right to reverse the effect.

For example, I'll use #shape and #inside:

```
#shape {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -60deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateX( -60deg );
}
#shape #inside {
    //what do I put here to reverse the perspective effect?
}
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle including HTML codes

Comment: just give the `#inside` element its own transform perspective property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use a wrapper div that contains both `#shape` and `#inside`. That way the text content won't get changed at all.  See, e.g., [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/9kSFF/).  Basic idea:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="shape"></div>
    <div id="inside">
        Some content.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#shape {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    color: #511;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
#shape.transform {
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -60deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateX( -60deg );
}
```

You may find, however, that you want to apply some special styling to the inside text when the shape is transformed.  Easiest way to do that is to assign the `transform` style to `#wrapper`.  E.g., [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/qp9T6/).

```
#wrapper.transform #shape {
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -60deg );
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateX( -60deg );
}
#wrapper.transform #inside {
    transform: translate(50px, 100px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 100px);
}
```